# Why am I getting a 400 error?

Tags: javascript, httprequest, stripe-payments

I am making a post request to add a subscription to a user, but I get this error `Result: Request failed with response code 400` https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#create_subscription

```
Parse.Cloud.define("Subscription", function(request, response){
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
method:"POST",
url: "https://" + 'sk_test_***' + ':@' + 'api.stripe.com/v1' + "/subscriptions/" + 'plan=' + request.params.customerId + 'customer=' + request.params.plan,
success: function(httpResponse){
  response.success(httpResponse.data);
},
error: function(httpResponse){
  response.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: As this is a POST request, it is a bit odd that you are providing parameters in the URL. What is the result if you change the method to GET?

Comment: It should be a post request and the problem with this is that your providing parameters in the url which is not correct.

Comment: @HassanAbbas it is a post request and I assumed that the url is incorrect. It would be awesome if you could take a look at the link I updated the question with and help me figure out the correct link

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd suggest you go to your [Stripe dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs) and review the logs to see what the actual error was - that might help clear this up for you.

I'm not very familiar with Parse Cloud, but just wandering around the code I see that's based on the [`request` module](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/blob/master/src/cloud-code/httpRequest.js#L58) so based on how that library handles [POSTing forms](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#forms), I think it should probably look like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("Subscription", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://" + 'sk_test_***' + ':@' + 'api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions/',
        form: {
           plan: request.params.customerId,
           customer: request.params.plan
        },
        success: function(httpResponse) {
            response.success(httpResponse.data);
        },
        error: function(httpResponse) {
            response.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this just to check. Furthermore your url is wrong

```js
Parse.Cloud.define("Subscription", function(request, response) {
  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions -u sk_test_"+ 'User_id'+ '-d plan=' + request.params.customerId+ '-d customer='request.params.plan",
    success: function(httpResponse) {
      response.success(httpResponse.data);
    },
    error: function(httpResponse) {
      response.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
    }
  });
});
```

Replace your url in the correct format. I hope it helps.

Comment: This is completely wrong.  He does need a POST request to do what he's doing, and your 'url' is a combination of an actual URL and some CURL command line options.

Comment: This answer was just to check whether he receives the response or not. It is because i wanted to make sure the request is made and a response is received.